# passar o id de um input para outra pagina

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Eu tenho um formulário que nos *inputs* tem o campo `id` e ao enviar o formulário queria recuperar esses valores no meu código.

```
<form  action="edit.php" method="post"]>
    <label class="" >
     <span class="legend">Requisito 1 :</span>
     <input type="text" name="req1" id="1"value="teste 1" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></label>

     <label class="" >
     <span class="legend">Requisito 2 :</span>
     <input type="text" name="req2" id="2"value="teste 2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></label>
</form>
```

Então quando pressiono em enviar, na página *edit.php*, recupero o valor de cada *input* dessa maneira

```
$req1 = $_POST['req1'];
$req2 = $_POST['req2'];
```

Então como faço para recuperar o valor `id` de cada *input* e enviar para a pagina `edit.php`

Comment: Pergunta: por quê você precisa do `id` do elemento? A função dele é identificar unicamente um elemento no DOM, no HTML. Se você precisa desse valor no PHP, você está implementando de forma errada.

Comment: pois na pagina edit eu do um updade na tabela onde o id que vem do input for igual ao do banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentado, a função da propriedade `id` é identificar unicamente um elemento no DOM, no HTML. Se você necessita deste valor no PHP, você não deve utilizar este atributo. Primeiro, porque não faz sentido. Segundo, porque essa informação não é passada através do protocolo HTTP para o PHP. A forma correta é armazenar o valor desejado em um campo do formulário, do tipo `hidden` caso não queira que ele apareça na página.

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    <label class="" >
        <span class="legend">Requisito 1 :</span>
        <input type="text" name="req1" value="teste 1" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="req1_id" value="1">
    </label>

    <label class="" >
        <span class="legend">Requisito 2 :</span>
        <input type="text" name="req2" value="teste 2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="req2_id" value="2">
    </label>
</form>
```

Com o PHP, você poderá recuperar os dados com:

```
$req1 = $_POST['req1'];
$req1_id = $_POST['req1_id'];

$req2 = $_POST['req2'];
$req2_id = $_POST['req2_id'];
```

Comment: muito bom não tinha pensado em fazer dessa maneira

Answer (score 0):

O valor name e id são os mesmos.
Dentro da página edit.php faça o seguinte

```
<?php 

$req1 = isset($_POST["req1"])?$_POST["req1"]:"";
$req2 = isset($_POST["req2"])?$_POST["req2"]:"";

echo $req1 ." ". $req2;

Teste ai.

?>
```

Comment: Assim é obtido o valor em `value` do `input`. A pergunta é sobre como obter o valor em `id`. Acredito que você não entendeu muito bem o que se pede.

Comment: Verdade, ele queria o nome do id="Aqui" do input.